# What is the differences between Modules & Layers in Nuxt 3?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I have spent several hours learning about modules and layers in Nuxt 3, but I'm unsure about the exact differences between them. With layers, we have the ability to share components, pages, composables, and configurations between multiple projects in a monorepo. On the other hand, modules also allow us to achieve this, but with an additional step of configuration. I would like to understand if there are any distinctions between them in terms of their use cases.

Comment: This recent video from the latest nuxt nation conference can give a clear vision about the difference https://youtu.be/dWXRiBQw_lE?t=97